# BC30002 Error When Compiling VB Project with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit

Tags: vb.net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm using the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit to compile a Visual Basic project and generate .dll file with following compilation options.

```
VisualBasicCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary, optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Debug);
```

Following error is thrown by the emitter for all VB projects I tried to compile. Please advice how to resolve this.

> vstest.executionengine.x86.exe Error: 0 : xxxxx -,
>   C:\Projects\xxxx\xxxxx\My Project\Settings.Designer.vb(67,48): error
>   BC30002: Type 'Global.xxxx.xxxx.Console.VBTestApp.My.MySettings' is
>   not defined.

Answer (score 1):

To compile the generated Settings.Designer.vb file correctly, you have to set the root namespace of the project to the same one the file was generated with. In your case, that seems to be `xxxx.xxxx.Console.VBTestApp`, so your options should be:

```
new VisualBasicCompilationOptions(
    OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,
    optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Debug,
    rootNamespace: "xxxx.xxxx.Console.VBTestApp")
```

Comment: I have tried this but didn't work, I have further described the issue in following
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227185/compiler-issue-in-visual-basic-project-with-microsoft-codeanalysis-emit

Comment: Does "didn't work" mean that it didn't solve the issue you asked about or that it didn't solve other issues you have? If my answer actually answered the issue you asked about, consider accepting it.